# click a button that I don't know the id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

hello your help with a js code

I have the following structure

```
<span>
 <span>
  <input/>
 </span
 <button>
 </button>
</span
```

My question is how can I invoke the click on the button?
I have tried the following code
$("#938552dd-ed5a-4bea-833b-41f110a1c366").closest('wInput-date').children("button").trigger("click");

but I can't get it if you help please.

```
<span class="k-datepicker wInput-date k-valid telerik-blazor k-input k-input-md k-input-solid k-rounded-md" data-id="cf018d18-c08c-477f-8a91-213944083232" data-val-id="938552dd-ed5a-4bea-833b-41f110a1c366" _bl_2d436386-enter code here7760-4ba0-9a8b-18c6033ed832="">
      <span class="k-dateinput k-valid telerik-blazor k-input k-input-md k-input-solid k-rounded-md" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
        <input class="k-input-inner" id="938552dd-ed5a-4bea-833b-41f110a1c366" tabindex="11" data-id="793b152c-d5e6-44b8-abef-fee3838ad1f5" type="text" _bl_cf0feb89-9608-41f7-a7d0-bcfab324c628="">
      </span>
      <button class="telerik-blazor k-button k-input-button k-button-solid k-rounded-md k-button-rectangle k-button-md k-button-solid-base k-icon-button" id="8ec8f7d4-af4e-4340-9540-e424aa647b95" data-id="e0f6604d-8572-4aac-850d-d648a4c5ff37" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false" type="button">
      <span class="k-icon k-i-calendar k-button-icon"></span>
      </button>
</span>
```

Comment: can you please clarify what you want? 
your current code fire the click when you `click` event on `button`  when  the `text` `input ` clicked

Comment: @OmarTammam I want to click on the button, but the button has no id, the only one that has an id is the input, that's why in my code I use that input to get the parent, and thus look for the button, and simulate the click

Comment: I got it you need to fire the click event of this `button` right? 
answer submitted, please check let me know if it suits your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` missed at  the query selector of `closest('.wInput-date')`

here is the snippet after the edits

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#938552dd-ed5a-4bea-833b-41f110a1c366").closest('.wInput-date').children("button").trigger("click"); 
   //can also use .click() works like trigger 
});
```

to make sure that it really fired please add this block and check the console

```
$(".k-button").click(function(){
console.log("clicked");
});
```